# Iterating through a column of array of arrays without a loop

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
           asks                                                        bids                                   lastUpdated   
0   [[0.09245, 1654], [0.09265000000000001, 506], ...   [[0.09148, 121], [0.09141, 183], [0.09134, 550...   2020-04-19 00:02:24.464     
1   [[0.09245, 1654], [0.09265000000000001, 506], ...   [[0.09148, 121], [0.09141, 183], [0.09134, 550...   2020-04-19 00:02:24.464     
2   [[0.09245, 1654], [0.09265000000000001, 506], ...   [[0.09148, 121], [0.09141, 183], [0.09134, 550...   2020-04-19 00:02:24.464     
3   [[0.09245, 1654], [0.09265000000000001, 506], ...   [[0.09148, 121], [0.09141, 183], [0.09134, 550...   2020-04-19 00:02:24.464
```

What I need is to create a column `midprice` which for each row is equal to `asks[0][0] + bids[0][0] / 2`

Any idea on how to do that without a loop? like a lambda function? 
something like that: `df.assign(midprice = lambda x: (x['bids'][0] + x['asks'][0]) * 0.5)`

The output should be a column like the following:

```
midprice
0.091965
0.091965
0.091965
0.091965
```

Thansk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = (df
      .assign(topBid = df.bids.apply(lambda bid: bid[0][0] if bid else np.nan))
      .assign(topAsk = df.asks.apply(lambda ask: ask[0][0] if ask else np.nan))
      .assign(midprice = lambda x: (x.topBid + x.topAsk) * 0.5))
```